# Choosing a GUI framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I'm in an environment where applications have to be partitioned. I'm taking on a project that will involve building a GUI and I don't want to waste team time or IT team by getting the wrong framework and supporting applications.

Already I've built a Tkinter GUI and it was somewhat painful, but it was included.

Just doing some quick googling, and some say never use Tkinter and use PyQt, don't use PyQt due to licensing use PySide, etc...

Any recommendations? Doesn't have to be aesthetically pleasing, I am more interested in the backend complexity and structure of the code the GUI framework uses.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are off topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: SO is not very product recommendation friendly, sorry... So just some hints: Tkinter pro: included in a standard Python install, con: rather limited and AFAIK seldom used in professional grade software. PyQt pro: based on the well known and documented Qt framework, used in professional software, many tools such as a designer, con: very large framework that require some investment to be correctly used

Comment: Good to know, not really sure its worth a downvote but okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would recommend PyQt, which is **both** aesthetically pleasing and is simple to implement. It is well structured, [well documented](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html) and cross-platform. The syntax is pretty clean, the classes are easily extendable. There is a nice GUI editor called *Qt Designer*, which allows fast prototyping. The *.ui* files it creates can be directly loaded into PyQt (checkout `PyQt4.uic.loadUi`).

I cannot say anything about licensing, though - you have to figure out yourself.